# cross_val_score, different cv return different scores for the same method

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, scoring

I'm having difficulty understanding my result. I am running the same model, the same method, and the same settings, only with k different where cv = k. 
Please see the image below.

- When k = 4, the result looks good for `clf_apgd_l1` model,
- When k = 3, not good. there is one part that the `cross_val_score` is quite low, i.e. 0.03377111
- When k = 5, not good as well, one part of cross_val_score too low, i,e, 0.03426791

For the same data, I tested with another method, logistic regression, and the returned cvs looks good, for k = 3, all cross_val_score above 0.5.

Why do I have such different values for my `clf_apgd_l1` model (proportional odds model, l1 penalty, Accelerated Proximal Gradient Descent (APGD aka FISTA)) for different `cv`s? 
The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried to run your `k=3` case multiple times? Is it possible that this `0.03377111` is just due to random number?

Comment: Can you write your code out, rather than linking to a screenshot?

Comment: @EuRBamarth The source code/the input file) is as in the link:
https://github.com/xyXiangYu/Education/blob/master/Optimization_for_Data_Science/Project/project_xiang_yu_and_babin_jean.ipynb     Probably it is because of the numerical instability in my code. 
 It may be because the  lipschitz constant is estimated incorrectly, therefore a too large step size. 

Old code for the step size is : 

         lips_const = np.linalg.norm(X) ** 2  / 4 
         step = 1 /  lips_const    # step value to be analyzed 
 
New version, I remove the denominator '4', it looks good now.

Comment: @YilunZhang, I thought about it as well, but I do not think it is the case here Since I did not change the settings and i did not set random set for this one but not for that one.   

It should be something related to the step size or numerical stability.